# Convert the internal representation of a float stored in an integer to an actual float

Tags: c, floating-point, internal-representation

I have the internal representation of a `float` stored in a `uint32_t`. Suppose we have two of them with those conditions. I want to sum the two `floats` represented by the `uint32_t` and then store their internal representation inside another `uint32_t`. I've been trying a few things but I'm not sure if there is an easy or standard way of doing so. From my point of view, there are two problems:

1. Convert the internal representation stored in the `uint32_t` to a `float` (otherwise I wouldn't know how to sum them).
2. After the sum, store the resulting `float` internal representation in a `uint32_t`.

I've been looking at functions in C libraries and maybe it could be done with `printf` or `atof` but I have not managed to resolve it.

Comment: Can you use the `float` type and its arithmetic?

Comment: Yes, I can. But I don't know how to pass the internal value expressed by the integer to the float.

Comment: just_trying_to_learn_here "I've been trying a few things" --> Post that code.  The "standard way" depends on language.  As is, question is too broad.

Comment: I am working with C language and finally I decided to use memcpy() to go from uint32_t to float and viceversa.

Comment: Why should you store `float`s in `uint32_t` variables?  Why don't use `float`?  Or an `union`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I finally used memcpy() to solve it. I am not entirely sure that it is completely reliable but I think it works well.

```
//Generate the floats
float a = 1.0;
float b = 2.1;
uint32_t x;
uint32_t y;
//Copy the internal representation to x, y
memcpy(&x, &a, sizeof(float));
memcpy(&y, &b, sizeof(float));

//This would be the starter point of the problem described above
float c, d;
memcpy(&c, &x, sizeof(float));
memcpy(&d, &y, sizeof(float));

float r = c + d;
printf("The number is %f\n", r);
```

The number printed is 3.1000 as expected.

Comment: what you've done looks reasonable and should be portable across common systems.  AFAIK it's possible for a `float` to not be in 32bit IEEE754 binary float, but it's going to be a pretty exotic system in that case and you'll likely have other issues with your code

Comment: You run the risk of a buffer overflow in case `sizeof(float) > sizeof(uint32_t)`.  You should have used `memcpy(&c, &x, sizeof c);`.  This could truncate the copy if `sizeof(float) < sizeof c`, but it is definiterly safer in the cse described just now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you use a typed language to store things in incompatible containers, but let's see if this if of help to you:

```
union flt_int {
    float    f;
    uint32_t i;
};

...

union flt_int a, b;

a.i = val1;  /* val1 is the integer internal rep of a float */
b.i = val2;  /* idem. */
c.f = a.f + b.f; /* use the floating point representation to add */
/* now you have in c.i the internal representation of the
 * float sum of a and b as a uint32_t */
```